# Does the uniqueness of splitting fields up to non-canonical isomorphism fall from algebraic geometry?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Does the uniqueness of splitting fields up to isomorphism over the base field fall out from some deep results in algebraic geometry, or is it something special to fields which I shouldn't expect to pop out from nuclear weapons like base change theorem etc?

Comment: Without thinking about this at all deeply, I’d suggest that “nuclear” results will often have basic results in their underpinning, whether immediately obviously or not.

Comment: I agree with @Lubin. In this case I would bet heavily that it is impossible to prove such a result by using algebraic geometry (non-circularly).

Comment: I suppose you could say that your titular statement is a consequence of Grothendieck's Galois theory, which he develops purely categorically.